# Highcharts Multiple Bar Colours in X-Range

Tags: javascript, highcharts

It is possible to have different coloured data points on the same line in HighCharts?

I have managed to get multiple points on the same line by following the [Highcharts X-Range example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/studies/xrange-series/) and using:

```
/**
 * Highcharts X-range series plugin
 */
(function (H) {
    var defaultPlotOptions = H.getOptions().plotOptions,
        columnType = H.seriesTypes.column,
        each = H.each,
        extendClass = H.extendClass,
        pick = H.pick,
        Point = H.Point,
        Series = H.Series;

defaultPlotOptions.xrange = H.merge(defaultPlotOptions.column, {
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.yCategory}</b><br/>'
    }
});
H.seriesTypes.xrange = H.extendClass(columnType, {
    pointClass: extendClass(Point, {
        // Add x2 and yCategory to the available properties for tooltip formats
        getLabelConfig: function () {
            var cfg = Point.prototype.getLabelConfig.call(this);

            cfg.x2 = this.x2;
            cfg.yCategory = this.yCategory = this.series.yAxis.categories && this.series.yAxis.categories[this.y];
            return cfg;
        }
    }),
    type: 'xrange',
    forceDL: true,
    parallelArrays: ['x', 'x2', 'y'],
    requireSorting: false,
    animate: H.seriesTypes.line.prototype.animate,

    /**
     * Borrow the column series metrics, but with swapped axes. This gives free access
     * to features like groupPadding, grouping, pointWidth etc.
     */
    getColumnMetrics: function () {
        var metrics,
            chart = this.chart;

        function swapAxes() {
            each(chart.series, function (s) {
                var xAxis = s.xAxis;
                s.xAxis = s.yAxis;
                s.yAxis = xAxis;
            });
        }

        swapAxes();

        this.yAxis.closestPointRange = 1;
        metrics = columnType.prototype.getColumnMetrics.call(this);

        swapAxes();

        return metrics;
    },

    /**
     * Override cropData to show a point where x is outside visible range
     * but x2 is outside.
     */
    cropData: function (xData, yData, min, max) {

        // Replace xData with x2Data to find the appropriate cropStart
        var crop = Series.prototype.cropData.call(this, this.x2Data, yData, min, max);

        // Re-insert the cropped xData
        crop.xData = xData.slice(crop.start, crop.end);

        return crop;
    },

    translate: function () {
        columnType.prototype.translate.apply(this, arguments);
        var series = this,
            xAxis = series.xAxis,
            metrics = series.columnMetrics,
            minPointLength = series.options.minPointLength || 0;

        H.each(series.points, function (point) {
            var plotX = point.plotX,
                plotX2 = xAxis.toPixels(H.pick(point.x2, point.x + (point.len || 0)), true),
                width = plotX2 - plotX,
                widthDifference;

            if (minPointLength) {
                widthDifference = width < minPointLength ? minPointLength - width : 0;
                plotX -= widthDifference / 2;
                plotX2 += widthDifference / 2;
            }

            plotX = Math.max(plotX, -10);
            plotX2 = Math.min(Math.max(plotX2, -10), xAxis.len + 10);

            point.shapeArgs = {
                x: plotX,
                y: point.plotY + metrics.offset,
                width: plotX2 - plotX,
                height: metrics.width
            };
            point.tooltipPos[0] += width / 2;
            point.tooltipPos[1] -= metrics.width / 2;
        });
    }
});

/**
 * Max x2 should be considered in xAxis extremes
 */
H.wrap(H.Axis.prototype, 'getSeriesExtremes', function (proceed) {
    var axis = this,
        dataMax,
        modMax;

    proceed.call(this);
    if (this.isXAxis) {
        dataMax = pick(axis.dataMax, Number.MIN_VALUE);
        each(this.series, function (series) {
            each(series.x2Data || [], function (val) {
                if (val > dataMax) {
                    dataMax = val;
                    modMax = true;
                }
            });
        });
        if (modMax) {
            axis.dataMax = dataMax;
        }
    }
});
}(Highcharts));


// THE CHART
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'xrange'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Item List'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        min: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 3)
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: '',
        categories: ['Item 1', 'Item 2'],
        reversed: true
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Project 1',
        // pointPadding: 0,
        // groupPadding: 0,
        borderRadius: 5,
        pointWidth: 10,
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 3),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 4),
            y: 0
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 6),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 7),
            y: 0
        },
        {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 11),
            y: 0
        },
        {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 3),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 6),
            y: 1
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 4),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 7),
            y: 1
        }], color: '#BF0B23'
    }]

});
```

Demo: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2phb21yc)

I also modified the color of the bars by adding "color: '#BF0B23'", however I'd like to render the 3 bars in "Item 1" in different colours. Any ideas if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same customization of color that you have done on the `series` on each `point` individually. Setting color on each `point` override the `series` color, just like `series` color overrides `plotOptions` color. The most specific value is used.

For example, in your case ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2phb21yc/1/)):

```
data: [{
    x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 3),
    x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 4),
    y: 0,
    color: 'blue'
}]
```

Comment: Excellent thanks, I thought I'd read the documentation that the color was applied at a series level but this makes perfect sense.